# How to pass list of nested lists into JPA native query

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jpa

I need to create a JPA native query relevant to the example below:

```
select * from inventory where (server, product) in (('server1','product1'), ('server2','product2'), ('server1','product3'));
```

I have created a native query:

```
@Query(
            value = "select server, product from inventory where (server, product) in (:myList)",
            nativeQuery = true
    )
    List<Product> getProducts(List<List<String>> myList);
```

But when I pass List of Lists as an argument:

```
List<List<String>> myList= Arrays.asList(
    Arrays.asList("server1","product1"),
    Arrays.asList("server2","product2"),
    Arrays.asList("server1","product3")
);
List<Product> products = myRepository.getProducts(myList);
```

I get an error

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
```

I use Oracle database. Please tell me, what am I doing wrong?

This question is **not about passing a flat List** into a native query to filter db results by 1 column (this works fine) but how to pass **a list of nested lists** into a query **to filter db results by 2 columns**.

Comment: Hello @Ula, you have to parse you generic list to a String :) before continue tho

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. However, when I tried to pass it as a flat string, it also didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working solution. I had to use dynamic queries with Specification and CriteriaBuilder.

I created a model class:

```
public class SrvProdTuple {
    String server;
    String product;
    // + getters
}
```

Specification:

```
public class mySpecification {

public static Specification<Product> getProducts(
        List<SrvProdTouple> myList
) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        myList.forEach(srvProdTouple -> {
            List<Predicate> srvProdPredicates = new ArrayList<>();

            srvProdPredicates.add(
                cb.equal(root.get("server"), srvProdTouple.getServer())
            );
            srvProdPredicates.add(
                cb.equal(root.get("product"), srvProdTouple.getProduct())
            );

            predicates.add(cb.and(srvProdPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{})));
        });

        return cb.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
    };
}
```

And usage (I used a JPA method findAll(Specification specification) ):

```
List<SrvProdTouple> myList= Arrays.asList(
    new SrvProdTouple("server1","product1"),
    new SrvProdTouple("server2","product2"),
    new SrvProdTouple("server1","product3")
);
List<Product> products = myRepository.findAll(mySpecification.getProducts(myList));
```

Comment: Does the generated query hit (server, product) index in your case (if you have one)?
I just tried this solution and it generates queries like
```... where server = ? and product = ? or server = ? and product = ? or ...```

Answer (score 0):

Missing parentheses or commas have been known to throw this error.

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
```

So i think it,s **parsing of your generic list to a String**.

Please take care of parsing your data to a String , i would recommend you using a String as parameter to your getProducts method, otherwise your should be parsing the list in that function before adding it to your query:

Here is an example how you could parse your generic list:

```
 String myListToStr = "";
    for(List<String> list : myList){
        myListToStr += "(\"" + String.join("\",\"", list) + "\")";
    }
    myListToStr = myListToStr.replace(")(", "),(");
    System.out.println(myListToStr);
```

**Result:**
**("server1","product1"),("server2","product2"),("server1","product3")**

Exactly what you need in this case.

Hopefully, you will be good with this solution. Make sure to mark this as answer if it does solve your problem!

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. However, when I tried to pass it as a flat string, it also didn't work.